# Django Admin Slow after Postgresql pg_dump

Tags: django, performance, postgresql, django-admin, rds

I have a well functioning remote PostgreSQL instance running in the cloud (Amazon RDS). I wanted to get a local copy for development. The remote instance is on Ubuntu and I am using postgres.app locally on a Mac. I took this approach:

```
psql -h localhost -U <superuser> template1 -c 'CREATE DATABASE <thedbname>;'
pg_dump -U <remoteuser> -h <remotehost> <thedbname> | psql -h localhost -U <localsuperuser> <thedbname>
```

The data came across and loaded up. I added a local djangouser and put it in my settings.py. When I tried to connect I was hit with this message:

```
ProgrammingError: permission denied for relation django_site
```

I searched around and then applied this:

```
psql <mydbname> -c "GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public to <djangoappusername>;"
psql <mydbname> -c "GRANT ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public to <djangoappusername>;"
psql <mydbname> -c "GRANT ALL ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public to <djangoappusername>;"
```

That allows me to "runserver." I browse the site and all the data is there, it's blazingly fast and operates as expected. But then I loaded the /admin/ . . . it's DOG slow. I can login in and move around but it takes 90 seconds to move from screen to screen (Chrome shows "connecting..." in the lower left). It's not a very large DB. Everything but /admin/ access is great. I did remove the old admin.pyc, no effect.

The one thing I wonder about is the  role that I used, I didn't use the remote superuser, I used the role that was created when I set up the RDS instance of PostgreSQL, this is what \du looks like out there, and I used the first role:

```
                                  List of roles
   Role name   |                   Attributes                   |    Member of    
---------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------
 <remoteuser>  | Create role, Create DB                         | {remotesuperu}
 <remotesuperu>| Cannot login                                   | {}
 <rdsadmin>    | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

One more thing, these are my local roles, the  is the owner of the database:

```
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 <djangou> | Create DB                                      | {}
 <superu>  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 <dbowner> | Create role, Create DB, Cannot login           | {}
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix the slow admin properly, or I will happily drop the DB and bring it over again if there is a better way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I opened up developer tools, the admin was trying to fetch the css & js from the "collect static" on a remote EC2 instance that was not running. I fired it up so it can access those files and all is good. I will leave the question and answer on the off chance it helps someone in the future.